# How to use onRetryExhaustedThrow in order to return original HttpStatusCode and message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create a custom retry method but i don't understand how it works.

In fact, I just want to try again several times and then, if all the attempts failed, return an exception with the last http status code, the http status message and the response body.

Is it possible to do that with webflux ?

This is my code below :

```java
    private RetryBackoffSpec retryServerError() {
        return Retry.backoff(3, Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
                    .filter(this::isServerError)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "an error message"));
    }

    private boolean isServerError(Throwable throwable) {
        return throwable instanceof HttpServerErrorException;
    }

    public void ResponseEntity<U> post(Class<Void> responseClass, Function<UriBuilder, URI> uri, MyBodyObject body) throws WebClientException, RestClientResponseException {
        return this.getWebClientBuilder()
                   .build()
                   .post()
                   .uri(uri)
                   .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(body))
                   .retrieve()
                   .toEntity(responseClass)
                   .retryWhen(retryServerError())
                   .block();
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrySignal allows you to get the exception that caused the retry.

```
private RetryBackoffSpec retryServerError() {
    return Retry.backoff(3, Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
        .filter(this::isServerError)
        .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
          HttpServerErrorException ex = (HttpServerErrorException) retrySignal.failure();
            HttpStatus statusCode = webException.getStatusCode();
            String responseBodyAsString = webException.getResponseBodyAsString();
            //whatever you want to do with it
          
        });
  }
```

Comment: you could just throw the original error without a cast`.onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure()))`